# Load youtube player api asynchronously on jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I need to load the youtube iframe player with api on a jquery change event but it only shows how to load it when the script is loaded.

This is the script they use to load the player with the api.

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

I need to wait to fire this until my change event is fired so inside this..

```
 $(document).on("change","#yt-url", function() {
     youtubeUrl = $(this).val();
     youtubeId = youtube_parser(youtubeUrl);
     // Load the youtube player with api
 });
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd just need to encapsulate the code creating the player into a function, which is called only by given event

```
$(document).on("change","#yt-url", function() {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Dmitry's example works, but I've got two modifications. First, check to see if the API is already loaded (whether `YT.Player` is defined) and only load the API if it isn't. Second, you might as well use `$.getScript()` since you mentioned you're using jQuery.

There's an example of this approach at https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/source/browse/static/js/ytdl/player.js

Comment: Nice example, you should add the code to your answer in addition to the link.